# Element is not clickable in Chrome Headless in robot framework. In normal mode everything ok

Tags: robotframework, google-chrome-headless

I'm writing test in robot framework. Problem is that this test failes on one step, by clicking some element on the page only on headless chrome mode. In normal chrome mode everything ok.

Below, appeared error in headless:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span>...</span> is not clickable at point (366, 840). Other element would receive the click:
```

Also, i will provide step in which test failes:

```
Click product
    [Arguments]    ${product}
    wait until page contains element    //span[text()='${product}']
    scroll element into view    //span[text()='${product}']
    click element    //span[text()='${product}']
```

I tried a few attempts, by setting time delay before click, scrolling element into view, nothing happened.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and edit your post. currently there is no clarity how the html code of element looks like. Don't add the picture of element its bad practice no one will write the code from image for you. Add the html as part of post itself

Answer (score 0):

Error message says: `Other element would receive the click`

This means that your are trying to click on element that is either fully or partially covered by another html element. For example, there's a toast or another element in same location but with higher Z order. Now, if you just rely on `Scroll Element Into View` keyword, it will only ensure that the element is within a viewport, not actually fully visible.

SeleniumTestability plugin has few keywords to avoid these sort of cases: `Is Element Blocked` will return  True or False if the element you want to interact with is actually blocked or not. `Get Element At` will return you the topmost element in that given location and then `Hide Element`/`Show Element´ can be used to temporarily hide/show the element that would be blocking the element that you want to interact with.

Comment: Thank's for advice!

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
Open Browser    about:blank    chrome
Maximize Browser Window
```